# Why my cat responds instantly to any movement?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

Whenever there is any movement of any kind Bhutu (our cat's name) instantly gets excited. It may be our legs, arms, any vegetable, water bottle, TV remote everything. And she instinctively tries to bite whatever thing is moving. Also she tries to grab it with claws. Although if it is our limbs she doesn't apply pressure of jaws.

In case of distant objects, she is usually unable to figure it out until it moves. This includes birds and other cats.

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 4):

Cats have evolved in nature and food is often in short supply in nature. So a cat that hunts anything that moves will have an advantage over cats that don't.

A few generations of "domestication" will not change the fact that cats are hunters and  good ones too.

We think cats and kittens play and even if there is an element of fun in this the main goal for the cats is to hunt and kill. Cats are totally dependent on their hunting skills to survive and we can not change this.

When cats first came to the human settlements they came not to find people but because humans do attract rodents. Humans allowed the cats to stay because it was of mutual benefit for cats(they got prey) and for humans(less food was eaten or spoiled by rodents).